# Match string of side-menu item with the that of inner menu item under another side-menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a global variable which is set when `brand name` under **products** side-menu item is clicked, matching `brand name` under **Images** side-menu item gets selected. The image below helps give you more clarity.

[image]

The problem I am trying to resolve is to match the brand name such as **Amba-Jeeves** under **Products**, with the same brand appearing differently under the **Images** where it is **Amba-AB -> Jeeves** (split). This is what should by default be open when an user moves from **Products** section to Images section after choosing Amba-Jeeves under "Products Section" as an example. I'm unable to reach this sub-list item. Please advise me as to what should have been done.

[image]

The code written to store brand name to be used in the Image section is as follows.

```
        //Save the selected brand id
        var this_parent_id = $this.parents(".ui-accordion-content").attr('id');
        if (this_parent_id == "productsMenu") {
            selected_brand_info = {
                                    id : $this.attr('data-id'),
                                    name : $this.find('span').text()
                                };
        }

            // For Images make the last selected brand under products as the default selection
            var brand_name = selected_brand_info.name;
            alert(brand_name);
            if ((ui.newHeader[0].title == "images") && (brand_name !== undefined)) {
                if (brand_name.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                    var brandStringArray = brand_name.split(' ');
                    brand_name = brandStringArray[0];
                } else if (brand_name.indexOf('-') != -1) {
                    var brandStringArray = brand_name.split('-');
                    brand_name = brandStringArray[0];
                }
                $('#imagesMenu li span').each(function() {
                //Match brands and sub-brands
                if ($(this).text().indexOf(brand_name) > -1) {
                    // Traverse the child elements to find the submenu item.
                    if($(this).next("ul").length > 0) {
                        $(this).next("ul").show();
                        var sub_brand_name = brandStringArray[1];
                        alert(sub_brand_name);
                        // Find the match and activate it.
                        $(this).next("li").each(function() {
                            if ($(this).text().indexOf(sub_brand_name) > -1) {
                                $(this).dblclick();
                                return false; 
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(this).parent().dblclick();
                    }                       
                }   
                }); 
            }
```

Comment: can you create demo code ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create the demo code. Please let me know how.

Comment: With html and jquery code which will demonstrate above behaviour .Also , both image you have added in question looks same ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the images. I just added the correct image.

Comment: Add html code as well .

Comment: Can I share the access details with you to the application this script is on, on the staging server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222864/discussion-between-swati-and-pktg).

Comment: Hi Swati, I seem to have made some progress,

Comment: Hi Swati, this task was completed, thanks for your assistance. Could you please refer some online course to learn JS better?

Comment: I just refer to [this](https://api.jquery.com/) site and stackoverflow.